# How to create a column view in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I'm writing my own mode in Elisp. It's basically a simple crud application showing rows of data which can be manipulated via the minibuffer. I'd like to create a view for these rows which looks like the emacs package manager: columns of data nicely aligned. What's the best way to implement such a view?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer from phils got me on track. There are no tutorials or simple examples anywhere though, so I created one. Here is an example of a tabulated-list-mode derivative which has static data and can print the ID of the current column:

```
(define-derived-mode mymode tabulated-list-mode "mymode" "Major mode My Mode, just a test"
  (setq tabulated-list-format [("Col1" 18 t)
                               ("Col2" 12 nil)
                               ("Col3"  10 t)
                               ("Col4" 0 nil)])
  (setq tabulated-list-padding 2)
  (setq tabulated-list-sort-key (cons "Col3" nil))
  (tabulated-list-init-header))

(defun print-current-line-id ()
  (interactive)
   (message (concat "current line ID is: " (tabulated-list-get-id))))

(defun my-listing-command ()
  (interactive)
  (pop-to-buffer "*MY MODE*" nil)
  (mymode)
  (setq tabulated-list-entries (list 
                (list "1" ["1" "2" "3" "4"])
                (list "2" ["a" "b" "c" "d"])))
  (tabulated-list-print t))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the code for the package listing function you mention, you'll see that it employs `package-menu-mode` which derives from `tabulated-list-mode`.

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `package-menu-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `tabulated-list-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I use org-mode for this kind of task all the time.

This should be a starting point for your development, because you already have nice tables.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to tabulated-list there is [tblui.el](https://github.com/Yuki-Inoue/tblui.el), which provides `tblui-define` a macro that will create a derived major mode of `tabulated-list-mode`, fairly rapidly.

As well as making it easier to get the table view, it also provides a simple way to integrate with magit popup. So you can add quick shortcut keys and group them by actions.  So creating a tabulated list based 'app' is simpler.

Here's a simple example...

```lisp
(tblui-define ocodo/gh-run-list-tblui
              "GitHub Workflow Runlist"
              "Display workflow runs in a tabulated list."
              ocodo/gh-run-list-entries-provider
              [("startedAt" 15 nil)
               ("url" 1 nil)
               ("status" 10 nil)
               ("event" 10 nil)
               ("workflowName" 15 nil)]

              ((:key "w" ;; tiny popup
                :name browse-row-url
                :funcs ((?W "Browse URL for current run" ocodo/gh-run-list-browse-row-url)))))
```

The entries must be provided by a function, we're using

```lisp
(ocodo/gh-run-list-entries-provider)
```

Which fetches and transforms a github JSON run list, and makes it usable for `tabulated-list` (more on this below.)

Popup functions, we also have the tiny popup definition, which calls a function that opens a url at row.

```lisp
(defun ocodo/gh-run-list-browse-row-url ()
  "Open the url for the current row."
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-to-string
   (format "open \"%s\""
           (elt (tabulated-list-get-entry) 1))))
```

tabulated-list provides the functions you need to get the row entries or row id  at point:

`(tabulated-list-get-entry)` and `(tabulated-list-get-id)`

Use `(elt n entry)` to get the content at column n (zero based)

#### Transforming data

I won't delve too deeply into transforming JSON into tblui entries.

But the tl;dr is, you'd map from (output of `(json-parse-string JSON-STRING)`) a `vector` of `alists`, converting to a `list` of `lists` containing an entry id `(car)` and a `vector` of column values `(cdr)`.

The columns we define will need to match the column positions of values in a row vector.  So, in our example row entries be like this:

```lisp
;;(id [vector of col values])
(list 0 ["10m ago" "https://github.com/org/repo/actions/runs/60324234205" "completed" "push" "MyFlow"])
```

Structurally:

```lisp
(list 
  (list 0 [... column values ...])
  (list 1 [... column values ...])
  (list 2 [... column values ...])
  (list 3 [... column values ...]) 
  ;; ... etc ... 
)
```

- https://github.com/Yuki-Inoue/tblui.el
- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Tabulated-List-Mode.html -- For all the functions available for the tabulated list view which `tblui` creates.